# Can't connect to PostgreSQL db in Next.js

Tags: postgresql, next.js

I try connect to PostgreSQL db in Next.js but i get this error: "Error: Error connecting to database: fetch failed"

It occures in my data.ts file

```
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from 'next/cache';

export async function fetchAllProducts() {
    noStore();
    const data = await sql`SELECT * FROM product`;

  return data.rows;
}
```

My .env file

```
POSTGRES_URL="postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres"
POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING="postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres"
POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL="postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/postgres"
POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
POSTGRES_HOST="localhost"
POSTGRES_PASSWORD="password"
POSTGRES_DATABASE="postgres"
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.6.0",
    "@vercel/postgres": "^0.5.1",
    "next": "14.0.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prisma": "^5.6.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

There is interesting moment that Prisma can connect to my PostgreSQL db and create tables with data. But when i try to do the same with help @vercel/postgres it always fails. Why?

I tried to fetch data from local PostgreSQL db a got error